# Do not allow links between 2 nodes - Directed Graph Editor d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've made use of "Directed Graph Editor" - http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347 for my research project and I've updated it and now it looks like this - http://jsfiddle.net/fb89orLt/2/.
My question is that how can I not allow a link to be drawn between 2 blue circles (for example, I do not want to allow d3 to draw link between "Starbucks" & "Habitat for Humanity"). I was thinking on achieving something comparing the 2 nodes on the "drag-to-self" lines as already done in Directed Graph Editor, but couldn't think of a solution.

Here's the code fragment where a new node is added and the "drag-to-self" condition is checked:

```
enter code here

  // select node
  mousedown_node = d;
  if(mousedown_node === selected_node) selected_node = null;
  else selected_node = mousedown_node;
  selected_link = null;

enter code here

  // reposition drag line
  drag_line
    .style('marker-end', 'url(#end-arrow)')
    .classed('hidden', false)
    .attr('d', 'M' + mousedown_node.x + ',' + mousedown_node.y + 'L' + mousedown_node.x + ',' + mousedown_node.y);

enter code here

  restart();
})
.on('mouseup', function(d) {
  if(!mousedown_node) return;

enter code here

  // needed by FF
  drag_line
    .classed('hidden', true)
    .style('marker-end', '');

enter code here

  // check for drag-to-self
  mouseup_node = d;
  if(mouseup_node === mousedown_node) { resetMouseVars(); return; }

  // unenlarge target node
  d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
```

Please help me out in this issue. Thanks. Any help is greatly appreciated.